# hole punch for old type 126 and 110 film

Tags: film, negative-film, negative-scanner

New film has holes down both side like the old school tractor feed printer paper.

Older type 126 and 110 film only has 1 hole on 1 side approx every photo.

Are there any kind of hole punches to duplicate these holes on older type 126 and 110 film.

My film scanner requires the modern holes/tractor feed to feed the film in correctly in an automatic way.

Comment: What film scanner are you using?

Comment: film nikon 5000 ed

Comment: I don't think you can simply feed these film formats into your scanner, even if they had perforations along both edges - they're simply not the same width as 35mm film. You need to use a custom aftermarket holder, such as those from FilmScan-USA or Negative Solutions, and use that in conjunction with the MA-21 Slide Mount Adapter. Maybe I'm wrong, but that's my understanding.

Comment: FilmScan-USA seems to be out of business.  I could not connect to there website either .com or .net.  I am reaching out to negative solutions to see about there offerings.

Comment: yep, film scanners, aftermarket accessories - you are going to have to look at the used market for most all of it

Comment: This is an [X→Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/348605). Instead of asking about your perceived solution (which probably wouldn't work, even if you found such a device) to the actual problem, please ask about your root problem: How to scan old 110 and 126 negatives with the old perforation pattern using a Nikon Film 5000 ED.

Comment: @MichaelC  The problem with that is I have spent hours researching and have not found another device with a dmax anywhere near this scanner.  The best flat bed scanner for about $1000 is a 3.9, and the nikon is 4.9.  As far as finding a device I have been using the nikon FH-2 and it works its just very time consuming.  Each negative has to be moved back and forth to line up with the corresponding slot.  Maybe it loses a small amount of top or bottom, but I can deal with that.

Comment: @osullic  Negative Solutions  is a one man business, apparently and he responded to my email saying that for him, making one is too difficult.  Which I understand because he has a full time job, and this is only a side business.  So i would need another vendor more able to work with me.

Comment: I'm unable to help further.

Comment: @cybernard Please read my suggestion above again; "How to scan old 110 and 126 negatives with the old perforation pattern **using a Nikon Film 5000 ED**." Isn't that what you said above you were using?